# Spring controller method don't recognize parameter passed by jquery .ajax() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

In my project, I have the following .ajax() function, which should send the content of a  with multiple values to the server:

```
$("#btn_enviar").click(function(){
    var selecao_usuario=[];
    $('#selecao option').each(function(){
        selecao_usuario.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "lista_horario.html",
        data: { id_usuarios: selecao_usuario, id_evento: $('#id_evento option:selected').val() },
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#result").show();
        $("#result").empty().append( data );
    });
});
```

What happens is that, according to browser console, this is the parameters this function is sending to server:

```
id_evento "1"
id_usuarios[] "9"
id_usuarios[] "4"
id_usuarios[] "7"
id_usuarios[] "8"
```

and because this last parameter, I am getting this error from server:

```
HTTP Status 400 - Required String[] parameter 'id_usuarios' is not present

type Status report

message Required String[] parameter 'id_usuarios' is not present

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

the function above is sending the data for this method from my spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/lista_horario", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String lista_horario(@RequestParam("id_evento") String id_evento, @RequestParam("id_usuarios") String[] usuarios)
{
     ...
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Param name in Spring MVC has to match param name in request. In your case change param name from `@RequestParam("id_usuarios")` to `@RequestParam("id_usuarios[]")`.

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter is sent because of the `cache: false` option in the `ajax` call. To prevent caching of the response, jQuery adds the parameter `_` with a value that equals the current timestamp (the result of `Date.now()`). This way, the request is always different and is not cached by the browser. If it is causing problems, then disable the cache via server response headers and remove the `cache` parameter from your call to `ajax()`. I'm not sure, though, that this is the reason why you're getting an error. Try removing the argument and see if it works.

Comment: Ok, I did this change, but the problem still happening. I udpate the question to include the method which is the target of the request.

Comment: But are you getting the same error? If you took out the `cache` property from the call, you shouldn't be sending the `_` query parameter.

Comment: yes, i am getting the same error, but I am not sending the _ query parameter anymore.

Comment: Then the problem wasn't that parameter. However, I'm not an expert on Java or Spring. I suggest you to add the `java` and `spring` tags to your question, so people expert on those areas can help you.